# What is the input dimension for a LSTM in Keras?

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I'm trying to use deeplearning with LSTM in keras .
I use a number of signal as input (`nb_sig`) that may vary during the training with a fixed number of samples (`nb_sample`)
I would like to make parameter identification, so my output layer is the size of my parameter number (`nb_param`)

so I created my training set of size (`nb_sig` x `nb_sample`) and the label (`nb_param` x `nb_sample`)

my issue is I cannot find the correct dimension for the deep learning model.
I tried this :

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM

nb_sample = 500
nb_sig = 100 # number that may change during the training
nb_param = 10


train = np.random.rand(nb_sig,nb_sample)
label = np.random.rand(nb_sig,nb_param)


print(train.shape,label.shape)
DLmodel = Sequential()
DLmodel.add(LSTM(units=nb_sample, return_sequences=True, input_shape =(None,nb_sample), activation='tanh'))
DLmodel.add(Dense(nb_param, activation="linear", kernel_initializer="uniform"))

DLmodel.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='RMSprop', metrics=['accuracy', 'mse'], run_eagerly=True)
print(DLmodel.summary())

DLmodel.fit(train, label, epochs=10, batch_size=nb_sig)
```

but I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\maxime\Desktop\SESAME\PycharmProjects\LargeScale_2022_09_07\di3.py", line 22, in <module>
    DLmodel.fit(train, label, epochs=10, batch_size=nb_sig)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\input_spec.py", line 232, in assert_input_compatibility
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "sequential" "                 f"(type Sequential).

Input 0 of layer "lstm" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (100, 500)

Call arguments received by layer "sequential" "                 f"(type Sequential):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(100, 500), dtype=float32)
  • training=True
  • mask=None
```

I don't understand what I'm suppose to put as `input_shape` for the LSTM layer and as the number of signals I use during the training will changed, this is not so clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input to LSTM has to be in the following format:

```
[sample, timestep, n_features]
```

or in your notation

```
[nb_sig x nb_sample x n_features]
```

Therefore you need to reshape the training data to that format. Instead you have:

> so I created my training set of size (nb_sig x nb_sample)

As you can see that is 2D input not 3D. You are missing the 3D dimension which in your case seems to be number of features.
Simply add 1 extra dimension to the vector using `numpy.expand_dims()` https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html
and you should be good to go :) - assuming you have univariate time-series.

Comment: I see. I used the function you propose to extent the dimension to 3D: `train = np.expand_dims(train,axis = 0)` and `
label = np.expand_dims(label,axis = 0)` It is working now.

Answer (score 1):

The input to the LSTM should be 3D with the first dimension being the sample size in your case 500. Assuming input having shape (500,x,y), input_shape should (x,y).

Answer (score 1):

As per the Keras [documentation](https://keras.io/api/layers/recurrent_layers/lstm/), the LSTM layer takes a three-dimensional tensor as input, and requires one dimension dedicated to timesteps. Since you are using the default parameter time_major=False, the input should be in the form [batch, timesteps, feature].

This [related question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/274478/understanding-input-shape-parameter-in-lstm-with-keras) may help you understand LSTM input shapes better.